# No mapping exists from dbtype 30 to a known sqldbtype

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldbtype, dbtype

I am trying to populate specific datatable values into a table. I am using the table value parameter. While adding the tabletype parameter i am thrown to no mapping exists. Can you find the bug in this part.

Below is my .NET Call

```
cmdabsSQL = dbabsSQL.CreateCommand()
                    cmdabsSQL.CommandText = "SP_INS_ResponseTable"
                    cmdabsSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure                      
                    cmdabsSQL.Parameters.Clear()

                    With dbabsSQL
                        .AddInParameter(cmdabsSQL, "@SystemName", DbType.String, SourceSysName)
                        .AddInParameter(cmdabsSQL, "@ClientName", DbType.String, ClientName)
                        .AddInParameter(cmdabsSQL, "@TableValueTypeII", SqlDbType.Structured, tablevaluedParam)
                        .AddOutParameter(cmdabsSQL, PARAM_OUT_SQLMSG, DbType.Int32, 100)
                    End With                     

                    intResult = dbBRLASQL.ExecuteNonQuery(cmdBRLASQL)
```

The tablevaluedParam is decalred like below.

```
Dim tablevaluedParam As DataTable = dstDataset.Tables(1)
```

here dstDataset has two datatables and the values in the dstDataset tables are populated by a query.I am just mapping the recieved datatable to the type created.
 Below is my type

```
CREATE TYPE TableValueTypeII AS TABLE
(ResultId BIGINT,
AccountId nvarchar(255),
RecStatusDesc varchar(100),
MatchCount int)
```

And this is my stored proc part

```
Insert into ResponseTable(SrceSysNm,ClntId,GrpId,PrvdId,FileNm,AccId,RestId,
RespSendIn,CreatTs,LstUpdtTs,UserId)
select @SystemName,@ClientName,null,null,null,AccountId,ResultId,0,
GETDATE(),GETDATE(),'Batch' from @TableValueTypeII
```

The dataTable is in the same arrangement of the type created.

Comment: I'm going to guess it has something to do with `tablevaluedParam`.  Can you show how you are creating this variable?

Comment: tablevaluedParam consist of a datatable which is obtained by retrieving the values from another stored proc. I am just mapping the recieved datatable to the type created

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: .AddInParameter(cmdabsSQL, "@TableValueTypeII", SqlDbType.Structured, tablevaluedParam)

This line throws the argument exception

Comment: Dim tablevaluedParam As DataTable = dstDataset.Tables(1)

here dstDataset has two datatables 
and the values in the dstDataset tables are populated by a query. The datatypes of these are the same

Comment: Ya sure i have added that in the question. Any idea what am i missing

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled the same problem. Solution was simple dbabsSQL should be SqlDatabase explicitly instead of

```
Dim db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()
```

use

```
Dim db As SqlDatabase = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing it this way , worked perfectly for me ,

```
    Dim _DataReader As SqlDataReader = Nothing
    Dim SQLCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Your connection string")
    SQLCon.Open()
    Dim SQLCom = New SqlCommand

    With SQLCom
        .Connection = SQLCon
        .CommandText = "SP_INS_ResponseTable"
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim _Param1 As New SqlParameter("@SystemName", SqlDbType.Varchar)
        Dim _Param2 As New SqlParameter("@ClientName", SqlDbType.Varchar)
        Dim _Param3 As New SqlParameter("@TableValueTypeII", SqlDbType.Structured)
        Dim _Param4 As New SqlParameter(PARAM_OUT_SQLMSG, SqlDbType.Int32)          

        //pass the parameters values here 
        _Param1.Value = _SystemName
        _Param2.Value = _ClientName
        _Param3.Value = _TableValueTypeII
        _Param4.Value = _PARAM_OUT_SQLMSG

        .Parameters.Add(_Param1)
        .Parameters.Add(_Param2).
        .Parameters.Add(_Param3)
        .Parameters.Add(_Param4)    
    End With

    _DataReader = SQLCom.ExecuteReader()

    While (_DataReader.Read)
        Dim _Record As New (your own returned data type)

        With _Record 
            .SystemName = (_DataReader(0)) // make sure they are not null(_DataReader(x)) assign it to empty string if so
            .ClientName = (_DataReader(1))
            .TableValueTypeII = (_DataReader(2))
            .PARAM_OUT_SQLMSG = (_DataReader(3))
        End With
        return _Record
    End While

    SQLCon.Close()
    SQLCon.Dispose()
    SQLCom.Dispose()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create dynamic sql like below:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)

set @SQL = N'Insert into ResponseTable(SrceSysNm,ClntId,GrpId,PrvdId,FileNm,AccId,RestId,
RespSendIn,CreatTs,LstUpdtTs,UserId)
select '+ @SystemName+','+@ClientName+',null,null,null,AccountId,ResultId,0,
GETDATE(),GETDATE(),''Batch'' from '+ @TableValueTypeII

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Then pass the table name as a simple string value.

**Note: Please check for single quotes while forming dynamic sql**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but my question is the argument exception is thrown before executing the stored proc itself. while mapping the datatable into the tabletype created

Comment: @GladstoneJaffrey, ok my bad. are you using sql server?